# How to scroll dynamic textview in swift 4?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

I have a tableview in which 6 section, they have only 1 row.

[image]

I increase the size of the cell due to this code:

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
}
```

My problem is that when writing large text (a large number of lines), the text is closed by the keyboard and you can not see what you are writing.

How to make the tablivec automatically go up when the text is closed by the keyboard? I can not solve this problem for a long time. I ask for help.

I need to achieve this result.
[image: result]

Comment: You could achieve this by registering your ViewController for keyboardWillShow-Notification and change your constraint of your tableView by keyboardSize.height - i am not sure if this is what you want to achieve.
If that is what you want let me know and i will show you an example

Comment: @T.Werb please see the gif listed above. There is exactly the result that I want to achieve

Comment: @T.Werb this does not work

Comment: well, it does for me. but when i inspect your gif this is not exactly what you want to achieve since your complete UITableView's positions is above the keyboard. Like i said before if this could be a workaround for your problem i can post some code as answer if you want.

Comment: @T.Werb On gif - my varinat! Because when the textview increases, it will go to the keyboard. I repeat: I have 6 dynamic cells, they contain UITextView, the scroll is disabled. The cell is stretched depending on the filling with text.